# How can I run a function inside an Office Dialog Eventhandler function?

Tags: angular, typescript, office-js, excel-addins

I have this code in an Angular2 Microsoft Office Add-in project that displays an [Office Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) using the Javascript API.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, {height: 34, width: 20, displayInIframe: true},function (asyncResult) {
  if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    // TODO: Handle error.
    return;
  }

  // Get the dialog and register event handlers.
  dialog = asyncResult.value;

  dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.type !== Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived) {
      return;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/user'],1);
    dialog.close();
  });
});
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.router is undefined
```

Where the router is defined in the component constructor.

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router,
private location: Location) { }
```

So the question is, how can I use that router inside the DialogEvenentHandler callback function to navigate to that URL?

Comment: It looks like your constructor declares the router as type Router but does not actually assign it a Router object. So it's expected that it would be undefined.

Comment: How should I declare it?

Comment: I'm not an Angular expert, but since Router begins with a capital letter, I presume that it is a class so you can use the "new" operator to create a Router object.

Comment: The Router get's injected by the angular DI system, so everything is fine with his constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not using arrow functions for your handlers and your `this` context gets lost.

Change your handlers to arrow functions and everything should work just fine.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, {height: 34, width: 20, displayInIframe: true}, asyncResult => {
  // ...
  dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, asyncResult => {
    // ...
  });
});
```